# when is SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP fired?

Tags: c++, mouse, sdl

Im making a 2D topdown RTS and I need to make a selection box which will have 4 parameters(x,y of top right corner and x,y of bottom down corner).
Can anybody tell me when is the SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP fired??

Comment: Please search before asking next time.

Answer (score 2):

It literally says in the [documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent).

*SDL_MouseButtonEvent is a member of the SDL_Event union and is used when an event of type SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP is reported. You would access it through the event's button field.

An SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP event occurs whenever a user presses or releases a button on a mouse. *